# Using subprocess module to access passwordless SSH device

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, subprocess, ssh-keys

I'm attempting to build a GUI for monitoring some of the processes going on on a Raspberry Pi via SSH.

The Pi currently has a passwordless setup (I had previously used keygen to generate a password file) – I can simply type

```
ssh host@xxx.xxx.x.xx
```

into the terminal to access it without a password.

I am now trying to write a Python script to access the device, but am prompted for a password when I attempt to run

```
from subprocess import call
call(['ssh', 'host@xxx.xxx.x.xx'])
```

I've tried the *os* module as well, to no avail. Is there something I'm missing?

(Apologies if this has been answered before. I couldn't find anything in the same vein, and my programming skills are fairly poor)

Comment: Just want to say that your python code work perfectly without any issue for ssh access via ssh key. If it is not working, it is not because of the subprocess call.

Comment: Cheers for the input! I actually realised that I'd had a VPN enabled so that was the problem – I've since used Aif's paramiko suggestion below and everything's working fine

Answer (score 1):

This is because your terminal runs an `ssh-agent` which knows your ssh identities. Whereas your python script must have a blank environment, hence no access to your `ssh-agent`.

Also, you could rely on a lib such as [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). I found an [example using ssh keys](https://gist.github.com/batok/2352501) or this [SO answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829838/paramiko-connect-with-private-key-not-a-valid-openssh-private-public-key-fil).

Comment: Is there a way of pointing the Python script to the location of the ssh-agent?

Comment: You can try increasing verbosity of ssh invokation (-v or -vv for instance). Then you could use `env` to get the list of env vars and check whether your python has an `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` entry.

Comment: I'm realising that I might be out of my depth so I'm probably better restoring the password system. Thank you!